# Call view function using web3.js 1.2.6

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethereumjs

I am trying to call view only function, not sure whether this is correct procedure or not. Getting success in result but the result is in different format. Is this wrong ?

```
const NODE_ADDRESS = config.web3Provider;

    const sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('path_to_contract', 'utf8').toString();
    const compiledCode = compiler.compile(sourceCode, 1).contracts[':ContractName']
    const abi = JSON.parse(compiledCode.interface);

    async function send(web3, transaction) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                const options = {
                    to: transaction._parent._address,
                    data: transaction.encodeABI(),
                    gas: 210000,
                    gasPrice: 10000000000,
                };
                const receipt = await web3.eth.call(options);
                return receipt;
            }
            catch (error) {
                return error
            }
        }
    }

    async function run() {
        try {
            const web3 = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);
            const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddr);
            const transaction = contract.methods.getBuyerInfo();
            const receipt = await send(web3, transaction);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(receipt, null, 4));
            if (web3.currentProvider.constructor.name == "WebsocketProvider")
                web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
            if (receipt) {
                next(null, receipt)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            next(error, null)
        }
    }
    run();
```

Result :-

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000f61343ef22bbccc7221dcda85c5a69219ea00c2b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c50756e656574204b756d61720000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked!

```
const contractAddr = "0x......"
const sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('path_to_contract', 'utf8').toString();
    const compiledCode = compiler.compile(sourceCode, 1).contracts[':ContractName']
    const abi = JSON.parse(compiledCode.interface);

    const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi , contractAddr);
    contractInstance.methods.functionName().call((err, result) => {
        if (err){
            next(err, null)
        } else {
            next (null, result)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

`call` does not return a receipt but the actual value of the function, as it is executed locally on the node.

However the returned object is a promise, so you need to `await` it.

Comment: i have used `await` on call , is that what you are pointing to ?

Comment: Yes. The return value should be the return value of the functoin, not receipt. You get a receipt only if you send a transaction.

Comment: Okay. Thanks :) , i changed the process and made it a simple call transaction , removing options and it worked.

Comment: Good! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct :)